# Roster from external service

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

Is there a pattern to achieve a roster populated by an external service (much like the external authentication module) without having to rewrite the `mod_roster`?

My current approach is to use `mod_roster_odbc` and update the rosterusers table manually (or even replace it with a view as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11360759/efficient-external-rostering-with-mysql-and-ejabberd)).

The problem with this approach is that a user won't be notified of a new item in its roster unless it queries for it.

I've also looked into using `mod_admin_extra` (as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801087/how-to-fully-integrate-xmpp-on-a-web-site-with-registered-users?rq=1)) but I haven't found any good documentation and I'm not sure if:

- solves my problem;
- will it present any scalability issues (due to the nature of the product, the roster can change quite frequently).

Comment: Do you really need to use XMPP roster? If your client uses general XMPP client, you need it. If XMPP is the only channel for realtime notification, you may need it. But in other cases, you can manage your own friend list. You may have it already.

Comment: I need the roster to tell the client which users it can send messages to. There is going to be a specific client application but I want to make it compatible with general XMPP clients. And yes, the XMPP server is the only channel for realtime notifications.

Comment: what is your external user database? mysql?